# Files disappearing in the middle of a function

Tags: php, web-services, api, caching, unlink

Interesting problem that I ran into today, so I'm writing this post for advice for how to deal with this now and in the future with other parts of my application (and maybe help someone else).

### **Consider this method:**

```
protected function unlinkCachePath($cachePath) {
    if (!file_exists($cachePath)) {
        throw new \Exception("Invalid cache file path '$cachePath'");
    }
    if (!is_writable($cachePath)) {
        throw new \Exception("Check permissions for file path '$cachePath'");
    }
    $result = unlink($cachePath); // delete file
    if (!$result) {
        throw new \Exception("Problem deleting cache file '$cachePath'");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Pretty straightforward, right? Well, it turns out that the `unlink()` function was *intermittently* not working correctly. Which was odd, because I had a `file_exists()` check before attempting my `unlink()`.

But still, it was generating a 'file not found' error. So I went out to debug, to find out what the heck was going on.

### **Debugging attempt:**

```
protected function unlinkCachePath($cachePath) {

    // debug the cache path
    echo "testing cache path: $cachePath <br />";

    // check if the file exists
    $this->debugFileExists($cachePath,'1'); 

    if (!file_exists($cachePath)) {
       throw new \Exception("Invalid cache file path '$cachePath'");
    }

    // ...check again
    $this->debugFileExists($cachePath,'2'); 

    if (!is_writable($cachePath)) {
       throw new \Exception("Check permissions for file path '$cachePath'");
    }

    // ...and again
    $this->debugFileExists($cachePath,'3'); 

    $result = unlink($cachePath); // delete file

    // ...and again
    $this->debugFileExists($cachePath,'4');

    if (!$result) {
        throw new \Exception("Problem deleting cache file '$cachePath'");
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
private function debugFileExists($filePath, $attemptNumber) {
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $response = "pass";
    } else { 
        $response = "fail";
    }
    echo "file_exists() test $attemptNumber: $response <br />";
}
```

### **Results:**

```
testing cache path: /path/to/file.json
file_exists() test 1: pass
file_exists() test 2: pass
file_exists() test 3: fail
# unlink(file): No such file or directory
file_exists() test 4: fail
```

**Wait, WHAT??**

Here I am, scratching my head. How can the file exist, and then in the same function, suddenly not exist? Any insight on to what the heck could be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: just question why are you supressing the error on the unlink function @unlink($cachePath); ?

Comment: @Yehia-Awad I know it's not best practice to suppress errors; it's just for my dev environment where I have error reporting on but need to respond using valid JSON. Any errors being printed in the response screws up the body of my JSON.

Comment: have you tried to remove the supressed @ and check what error is it giving you?

Comment: @Yehia-Awad Yes. I'll change the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my application's API backend is PHP, while the frontend is angular. In rare cases, multiple frontend calls to an API, which hits `unlinkCachePath($cachePath)`, would happen simultaneously -- and *in the middle of a function*, the file would delete! Because of this particular problem, the issue was not caught by extensive testing.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Could you explain how you solved this issue? Thanks