# Can I use a dummy lock file for PHP to implement mutual exclusion?

Tags: php, concurrency, locking, mutual-exclusion

I was wondering whether this is a  good way to implement mutual exclusion on PHP:
You use PHP flock() and a dummy lock file.

Because flock() only allows one process to access a file.

```
$file = fopen("dummyLockFile");
flock($file, LOCK_EX)
//Critical section
fflock($file, LOCK_UN)
fclose($file)
```

Comment: I'm curious too; this is extremely relevant to an issue I've been having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657155/files-disappearing-in-the-middle-of-a-function

Comment: Yes. It's not perfect, but that's because PHP was not designed with threading, multiprocess, or IPC in mind.

Comment: If you're on Windows you can [use Notepad to lock a file](http://superuser.com/a/649819/496195).